# Extract head of an array using open_json?

Tags: sql-server, open-json

I am have sample JSON as below

```
{
    "12345": {
        "percent": 26,
        "avgPrice": 32,
        "avgNewOfferCount": 12,
        "avgUsedOfferCount": -1,
        "isFBA": true,
        "lastSeen": 653
    }
}
```

I am getting the array values but since my array head i.e. '12345' is not fixed but an ID I am not able to get it and I can't hardcode since ID will change.

I am trying as below:

```
SELECT @json j;

INSERT INTO [test].[test]
    SELECT      
    JSON_VALUE(j.[value],$.j) AS key,
    JSON_VALUE(j.[value],'$.percent') AS stat    
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j;
```

But getting NULL in the key column.

Comment: That query would error, due to a syntax error, not return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would have worked by simply selecting `j.[key]`.

```sql
SELECT      
    j.[key],
    JSON_VALUE(j.[value],'$.percent') AS stat    
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j;
```

But you are better off just using two levels of `OPENJSON`, one feeding into the next.

The first does not use a schema, so you get a list of `key` `value` pairs. `key` represents the property name, which in this case would be `12345`. Then you push the `value` into the next call.

```sql
SELECT
  j1.[key],
  j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value)
  WITH (
    [percent] int,
    avgPrice decimal(9,2),
    avgNewOfferCount int,
    avgUsedOfferCount int,
    isFBA bit,
    lastSeen int
  ) j2;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/SAaiZ-x2)

Comment: Not clear why the downvote